# Macro _self no longer possible in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, migration

This used to work in Craft 2:

```
{% macro richText(macroParam) %}
  {{ macroParam |striptags('<br><p><li><ul><a><strong><i>')|raw }}
{% endmacro %}

{# include the richtext macro on multiple occasion into another macro #}    
{% macro memberMolecule( entryParam ) %}
  {{ _self.richText(entryParam.body) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Now in Craft 3 this causes the error:

> Impossible to invoke a method ("richText") on a string variable
>   ("path/to/file/with/the/macro").

How do I have to rewrite this for Craft 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import the macro

```
{# include the richtext macro on multiple occasion into another macro #}    
{% macro memberMolecule( entryParam ) %}
    {% import _self as macro %}
    {{ macro.richText(entryParam.body) }}
{% endmacro %}
```